# Same unit of operation takes different length of time in two pretty similar queries

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

I have these two queries :

```
SELECT *
FROM ActionMessage am 
JOIN vTasks vt ON am.TasksSeq = vt.TasksSeq
JOIN Tasks t2 ON t2.TasksSeq = vt.UltimateParent
WHERE vt.UltimateParent = 1225 

SELECT *
FROM ActionMessage am 
JOIN vTasks vt ON am.TasksSeq = vt.TasksSeq
JOIN Tasks t2 ON t2.TasksSeq = vt.UltimateParent
WHERE t2.TasksSeq = 1225 -- NOTE: this is the difference between
```

The `vTasks` is a view that ,using left self-joins can go up to 4 levels, calculates the top-most parent of a given task.
When I run the queries the first one takes less than a sec but the second one takes 15 secs.
Then I had a look at their actual execution plans which I attached the image link if needed.

If you have a look at the picture there is an index seek operation in both of them.
It takes 30% of the whole query exec time according to the first plan.
The first plan belongs to the query with longer exec time.
So I can conclude that index seek would take 5 secs for the query 1.
We have the same operation in plan 2 but it clearly takes less than a sec to run.
I had a look at details of this operation in both plans but the stats and info looks the same.

**My question is** as the 2 queries are pretty much the same I at least expect the index seek in both would do the same operation. So Why are the execution time of them are this different?

[image: Query Exec Plans]

Here is a broader view of plan 2:
[image]

Comment: How many rows in vt as compared to t2 satisfy the respective conditions? Also you might want to update statistics https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx Tables defintions would also help\

Comment: It could be useful to see `vTasks` code.

Comment: Cost percentage and time are not always directly related. I would guess that this bold arrow on first plan (clustered index scan) takes most of time.

Comment: The second picture is not the *complete* plan of the second query, is it? Hard to believe the plans differ so much.

Comment: @Mihai, the view has as many rows as the task table. it only calculates the parent.

Comment: @Arvo, Sorry if that bold line would distract you. its just a separator I drew.

Comment: @AndriyM, I have added another pic to the post for 2nd plan.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Is the "First Exec Plan" an incomplete picture too? Were you trying to show only the differing parts of the plans?

Comment: @AndriyM, no both of them are the first nodes of the plans.

Comment: So it's a "yes" to both of my questions then. Both original "plans" were actually *fragments* of the plans and you were only trying to show those fragments because you thought they were the key differences between the plans, am I right? I can see now that the second plan has a Key Lookup operator at the same point as the first plan, but your first picture of the second plan didn't show that. I think it would be a good idea if you posted the complete plans for both queries posted.

Comment: @Sahand, I couldn't express myself properly. I meant that you should not only look at percentages on plan, but pay attention to bold arrows - SSMS doesn't usually assign big percentage to these parts, but in less than ideal conditions (not high-end disk subsystem) these bold arrows represent huge amount of repeated reads from disk/cache and often indicate inefficent part in your query (and cause real bottleneck).

Comment: @arvo thanks for your point. I did not notice the thick line.not good at reading execution plans though.i will have a closer look.

Comment: @Arvo, I had a look at the whole plan. So  the thick line estimated row count is only 11,406 compared to its actual row count which is around 7,700,000. Also we have many thick lines after this through the plan up to the end of it before Filter operation. so is this the number of recs Clustered index scan outputs? the number of rows in the table is only 11,408 which is very close to the estimated number I mentioned above. So can you please explain what is happening?

Comment: @Sahand, unfortunately I can't explain - I have no theoretical knowledge, I only play with each specific case until it clicks into place. First step would be updating statistics of all involved tables (with fullscan option, if data distribution is not even). Then playing with indexes (both adding and removing these). Then playing with join hints. If possible, replace 'select *' with specific field list - this may affect query plan substantially.

Answer (score 1):

In your first query you have a `JOIN` that tells the DBMS to do an *Clustered Index Scan* over an indexed entity that is `Tasks` table that will merged with the checking related parts to `Tasks` table as aliased by `t2` in `WHERE` statement, So you will have only one *Clustered Index Scan* at all.

But when in your second query you try to check over your view, DBMS will again load `Tasks` data -that is used by your view- in a new place of memory and do another *Clustered Index Scan* over that new loaded data.

---

I suggest you to optimize `ActionMessage` table that makes more effects in your query by adding an `Index seek (Non-Clustered)`.

Comment: Thanks, but does this affect non-clustered index seek on am table? Most of the query time is consumed by this part.

Comment: @Sahand *Clustered Index Scan* causes of your table structure you can check `Tasks` CREATE statement with `ActionMessage` and that's not most time consumer the most time consumption is not related directly to your plan ;).

Comment: I think i might be missing your point here. Actionmessage already has an index on tasksseq and its being used in indexseek on the plan.

Comment: @Sahand [Seeks are usually better than Scans but not at all situations](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42568/60970) ;).